# collapsible panel on top a map, suggestions how to build it

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

How to build this layout? https://i.stack.imgur.com/OR1rs.jpg

What kind of objects/views i should to use in my layout_activity.xml
to build a collapsible panel like that in the image on a layer above a map?

Could you give my some suggestion or a piece of pseudocode please?

The panel should open/close itself by a button and (optional) when the display is in landscape mode the panel should be on the right

i don't know how to start, does exist some alredy made component like that or i have to build it from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for can be accomplished with fragments. You can add a fragment at runtime and move them around as you like. Very good explenation as well as tutorials are available in the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html)